# How can i pass the text field value to php variable without submiting form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is the field and whatever user enter into it, i want to get that value through php variable in the same page without click or submit the form . $Coupan_code

HTML field:

```
<input name="id_coupon" type="text" id="id_coupon">
```

Comment: watch php , ajax, js tutorial

Comment: use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  lots of examples are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fundamentally incorrect requirement. HTML is all client side code whereas the PHP variable is a memory allocated on the server side. You must submit/pass the value to server side using Ajax, JQuery, API call to get the value from textfield to PHP variable on server side.

PHP variable can't be accessed from HTML/JS directly. You must hit the server side code to set the value.

Comment: Actually, I have generated coupons for my user and before submit the form it needs to validate, if coupon code is available in the database then user can avail the discount of particular course. How this could be achievable

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. Make an AJAX request by fetching the value from your textfield and send it to a server side PHP function which validates the coupon code entered by the user. Implement a callback handler function for your AJAX request which will receive the response from PHP code to give you the status if coupon code is validated or not and accordingly you handle the response to update the message to user or proceed further for its processing. You can look for any example of AJAx based PHP request and you can implement it quickly.

Comment: Thanks Gurdev. Finally get rid of it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate solution to your problem. You cant assign value to any variable. But there is one trick.

```
<input name="id_coupon_value" type="hidden" id="id_coupon_value">
```

Take an hidden field. and whenever user enters any value in tour text box, you can assign that value to hidden field. And you can use that wherever you want. Even after submitting the form as you will get that value after submitting the form.There is no other alternate way.